# How to send an image from one tabPanel to another tabPanel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need to create a dashboard full of images.

Each image should have a pickerInput() from shinyWidgets package associated. I include the image path into the label argument. My idea was to associate each pickerInput with each image. Makes sense what I did?

I used pickerInput because I want the use select the Panel he/she wants to send the image.

And then, after the user choose the panel the image is sent to the tabpPanel the user choosed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

 
ui <- fluidPage(
   
  
  titlePanel("Two Panels Image App"),
   
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Panel A",
             wellPanel(
               
               
               pickerInput(
                 inputId = "picker1a",
                 label = img(src = "www/panelA/image1a.jpg", width = "100%"),
                 choices = c("Panel A", "Panel B", "Panel C"),
                 selected = "Option A"
               ) ,
               
               pickerInput(
                 inputId = "picker1b",
                 label = img(src = "www/panelA/imagm1b.jpg", width = "100%"),
                 choices = c("Panel A", "Panel B", "Panel C"),
                 selected = "Option A"
               )  
               
               
             )
    ),
    tabPanel("Panel B",
             wellPanel(
              
               pickerInput(
                 inputId = "picker2a",
                 label = img(src = "www/panelB/imagem2a.jpg", width = "100%"),
                 choices = c("Panel A", "Panel B", "Panel C"),
                 selected = "Panel B"
               ),
               pickerInput(
                 inputId = "picker2b",
                 label = img(src = "www/panelB/imagem2b.jpg", width = "100%"),
                 choices = c("Panel A", "Panel B", "Panel C"),
                 selected = "Panel B"
               ),
                
             )
    )
  )
)
 
server <- function(input, output) {
   
}
 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The expected behavior is not clear in terms of the relationship between the picker label images and what happens when a picker selection is made.  Perhaps you could edit the question and using "picker1a" as an example and the user selects "Panel B"...Then what?  The "image1a.jpg" is displayed somewhere on Panel B?  The "picker2b" pickerInput changes its label to use the image1a.jpg image?  Something else?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you had in mind?

https://technophobe01.shinyapps.io/77875479/

Based on your code, my sense was to provide a working example. We start by creating a fluid page with three tab panels: (Two is fine, but three divine)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Image Panels"),
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "panelTabs",
    tabPanel("Panel A", uiOutput("panelAContent")),
    tabPanel("Panel B", uiOutput("panelBContent")),
    tabPanel("Panel C", uiOutput("panelCContent"))
  )
)
```

on the server side, we track the image assignments and observe when changes are made to the assignments. When the user selects a new panel for an image, we update the UI and move the image to the selected panel.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

images <- list(
  image1 = list(src = "panelA/image1a.jpg", panel = "Panel A"),
  image2 = list(src = "panelA/image1b.jpg", panel = "Panel A"),
  image3 = list(src = "panelB/image2a.jpg", panel = "Panel B"),
  image4 = list(src = "panelB/image2b.jpg", panel = "Panel B")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  imagePanels <- reactiveValues(panelAssignments = list(image1 = "Panel A", image2 = "Panel A", image3 = "Panel B", image4 = "Panel B"))
  
  # Generate panel content based on current image assignments

  generatePanelContent <- function(panelName, imagePanels) {
    uiElements <- lapply(names(imagePanels$panelAssignments), function(imageId) {
      if (imagePanels$panelAssignments[[imageId]] == panelName) {
        src <- images[[imageId]]$src
        fluidRow(
          column(4,
                 img(src = src, width = "100%"),
                 pickerInput(inputId = imageId, 
                             label = paste("Move", imageId, "to:"),
                             choices = c("Panel A", "Panel B", "Panel C"),
                             selected = panelName)
          )
        )
      }
    })
    do.call(tagList, uiElements)
  }
  
  # Observe pickerInputs and update panel assignments

  lapply(names(images), function(imageId) {
    observeEvent(input[[imageId]], {
      imagePanels$panelAssignments[[imageId]] <- input[[imageId]]
    })
  })
  
  # Generate UI for each panel based on imagePanels

  output$panelAContent <- renderUI({ generatePanelContent("Panel A", imagePanels) })
  output$panelBContent <- renderUI({ generatePanelContent("Panel B", imagePanels) })
  output$panelCContent <- renderUI({ generatePanelContent("Panel C", imagePanels) })
}
```

Hopefully, this will point you in the right direction.